# Push multiple arrays into object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to push the each element of 2 arrays into an object,
the number of a input, and the value of that input.

I This is my desired output

```
[{"span" : 1},{"value": 1}]
```

however, my object keeps returning empty. I'm not sure what I am missing here.

```js
$('#group').on('click', function() {
  var addFieldsArray = $('.add').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
 var addSpanArray = $('[name="span[]"]').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
 }).get();


 var obj = {};
 obj.final = [];
 for(var i=0; i< addSpanArray.length; i++){
  obj.final.push[{"span": addSpanArray[i]}, {"value": addFieldsArray[i]}]
 }
 console.log(obj.final);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="add[]" class="add" id="one"><span name="span[]" id="s-one">1</span>
<input type="text" name="add[]" class="add" id="two"><span name="span[]"  id="s-two">2</span>
<input type="text" name="add[]" class="add" id="three"><span name="span[]"  id="s-three">3</span>
<input type="text" name="add[]" class="add" id="four"><span name="span[]"  id="s-four">4</span>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="add[]" class="add" id="five"><span name="span[]"  id="s-five">5</span>
<input type="text" name="add[]" class="add" id="six"><span name="span[]"  id="s-six">6</span>
<input type="text" name="add[]" class="add" id="seven"><span name="span[]"  id="s-seven">7</span>
<input type="text" name="add[]" class="add" id="eight"><span name="span[]"  id="s-eight">8</span>
<br/>
<button id="group">Group</button>
```

Comment: `obj.final.push[{"....` - push is a function, it should be `obj.final.push(...)`

Comment: Do you really want `span` and `value` in separate objects, not together in the same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=example) is a function, so call it using parenthesis not square brackets:

```
obj.final.push[
//            ^
```

Should be:

```
obj.final.push({"span": addSpanArray[i]}, {"value": addFieldsArray[i]});
```

Comment: Ok that was part of the issue, but now with my formatting it is creating an object for both "span" and "value". How could i have it created an object for each "span" + "value" ?

Comment: @user2168066 The question says you want `[{"span" : 1},{"value": 1}]` that's what this answer does. Twisty's answer puts them in a single object.

Comment: @user2168066 It's simply `obj.final.push({"span": addSpanArray[i], "value": addFieldsArray[i]});`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterate using `.each()`?

```
$('#group').on('click', function() {
  var obj = {};
  obj.final = [];
  $(".add").each(function() {
    obj.final.push({
      span: $(this).next("span").html(),
      value: $(this).val()
    });
  });
  console.log(obj.final);
});
```